# Show data from a spreadsheet according to the selected data in another spreadsheet

Tags: excel, excel-2010

Probably this question is very rookie, but not really used to play a lot with Excel, anyway here I go.

I have 2 spreadsheets: A and B

In the spreadsheet "A" have the following info:

```
+----------+--------+-------+------+
|   DATE   |  CODE  | CORRL | CAPA |
+----------+--------+-------+------+
| 01/03/17 | 110104 |     5 |   28 |
| 01/03/17 | 110104 |     7 |   30 |
| 01/03/17 | 810107 |     5 |   30 |
+----------+--------+-------+------+
```

and in the spreadsheet "B" the following info:

```
+----------+--------+-------+--------+
|   DATE   |  CODE  | CORRL |   SN   |
+----------+--------+-------+--------+
| 01/03/17 | 110104 |     5 | 182694 |
| 01/03/17 | 110104 |     5 | 571394 |
| 01/03/17 | 110104 |     7 | 298435 |
| 01/03/17 | 110104 |     7 | 205785 |
| 01/03/17 | 810107 |     5 | 234519 |
| 01/03/17 | 810107 |     5 | 229787 |
+----------+--------+-------+--------+
```

So what I need is when I move through the records of the spreadsheet "A" only the records with the same value of DATE, CODE and CORRL in the spreadsheet "B" are shown

Example:
If I'm positioned in the 1st row of the spreadsheet "A" in the spreadsheet "B" only the first 2 records must be shown, that is:

```
+-----------+---------+--------+--------+
|   DATE    |  CODE   | CORRL  |   SN   |
+-----------+---------+--------+--------+
| 01/03/17  | 110104  |     5  | 182694 |
| 01/03/17  | 110104  |     5  | 571394 |
+-----------+---------+--------+--------+
```

and so on

Thanks

Comment: I believe you have a couple things going on, of which VBA might be more advantageous.  Yes you can do the simple countifs, but it appears you want some type of change_event to update the filter on Sheet B based on your activecell.row in sheet A.  Though, you "could" use a combo match+countifs on Sheet B and manually filter...

Comment: Are the worksheets in different workbooks?

Comment: yes Brad, as I said before, I have 2 spreadsheets: A.xlsx and B.xlsx

Comment: @cpastene yeah but that could be interpreted as 2 sheets in a single workbook, hence why I asked. Thanks for answering anyway.

Comment: ... it also changes the solution significantly.

Answer (score 0):

I have to say, this is one of the more different requests that I've seen for Excel functionality.

I think I have something for you.

Firstly, if you're not familiar with the VBA editor then you can access it by pressing **Alt + F11**.  Another way to access it is from the **Developer** tab in your ribbon, which is hidden by default.  To unhide it, change the ribbon to include it.

[image: Developer Tab]

From there you can get to the VBA editor as well as run macros.

[image: VBA Editor]

From within there, add the following code ...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim lngRow As Long, lngCol As Long, strDate As String, strCode As String, strCorrl As String
    Dim strKey As String, strSlaveKey As String, i As Long

    If objSlaveSheet Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    objSlaveSheet.Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    objSlaveSheet.Rows(1).Hidden = False

    If Target.Cells(1, 1).Row > 1 Then
        With Target.Worksheet
            strDate = .Cells(Target.Row, 1)
            strCode = .Cells(Target.Row, 2)
            strCorrl = .Cells(Target.Row, 3)

            strKey = strDate & "_" & strCode & "_" & strCorrl
        End With

        ' Now loop through all of the cells in the slave workbook.
        ' Start at the second row because the first has a header.
        With objSlaveSheet
            For lngRow = 2 To .Rows.Count
                strSlaveKey = ""

                For i = 1 To 3
                    strSlaveKey = strSlaveKey & "_" & .Cells(lngRow, i)
                Next

                strSlaveKey = Mid(strSlaveKey, 2)

                If strSlaveKey = "__" Then Exit For

                If strSlaveKey = strKey Then
                    .Rows(lngRow).Hidden = False
                End If
            Next

            .Activate
            .Cells(1, 1).Select
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

... into the worksheet where you want to trigger the selection from, this is your worksheet **A**.

Also in workbook **A**, create a new **Module** in the VBA editor and paste the following code ...

```
Public objSlave As Workbook
Public objSlaveSheet As Worksheet

Public Sub SelectSlaveBook()
    Dim objDlg As FileDialog, strFile As String, strSlaveSheetName As String

    strSlaveSheetName = "Sheet1"

    Set objDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)

    objDlg.Show

    If objDlg.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        strFile = objDlg.SelectedItems(1)

        Set objSlave = Application.Workbooks.Open(strFile, False, True)
        Set objSlaveSheet = objSlave.Worksheets(strSlaveSheetName)

        ThisWorkbook.Activate
    End If
End Sub
```

... before moving on, make sure you change the value of **strSlaveSheetName** to be the name of the sheet where your data is in your "Slave" workbook (**B**).

Finally in worksheet **A**, add the following code into the **ThisWorkbook** object ...

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    SelectSlaveBook
End Sub
```

... now close the master workbook (in your case, workbook **A**) and open it again.

You will be prompted for the location of the "Slave" workbook (workbook **B**).

Once you've given that location, select what you want to select and all things held constant, it should work for you.

Of course, if it needs tweaks to suit your exact requirement, that's always possible.

I hope it works for you.